# Calling "grep" and "head" from PHP

Tags: php, shell, grep, head

I'm trying to filter content of set of files in directory and output only first n lines using such command:

```
gzip -dc $(find %pathtofolder%) | grep 27990 | head -n 50
```

running this command in terminal takes few secs to complete. But when i run it from PHP it takes almost one hour, becouse total size of files is huge.
Seems like php waits until the gzip command is finished.
But if i simple run:

```
gzip -dc $(find /opt/data/bi/ets/20130616) | head -n 50
```

it gives results immediately.
I tried backquotes, exec, system.

here is php code:

```
$cmd = 'gzip -dc $(find '.$path.' | grep -E "'.$regexp.'") | grep -E "'.$this->_buildRegExp().'" | head -n '.$r['limit'];
$res = `$cmd`;
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with PHP here. I cannot see any PHP code.

Comment: $cmd = 'gzip -dc $(find '.$path.' | grep -E "'.$regexp.'") | grep -E "'.$this->_buildRegExp().'" | head -n '.$r['limit'];
and then exec($cmd)
but i simplified this command to minimum needed to reproduce

Comment: Well, you should put that in the question. It doesn't make sense without the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Use passthru instead of exec to get all output, not only last string

```
passthru($cmd, $output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: problem is that command doesn't stop after finding all 50 rows.
i'll replace exec with backquotes